# Why Context object is required for View Constructor

Tags: android, view, constructor, android-context

Why is it required to pass on context object for view constructor. How a view and context are related to each other.

Comment: Context provides access to resources, such as configuration and settings. There's no technical reason why it's required, it could be implemented as a static member, but this approach has benefits in terms of unit testing and dependency injection. For a concrete explanation you'll probably have to ask one of the android team!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically context is passed to the view so that the system know where and how(which activity,screen,application etc related to this view) to display the view,what are things related to the view..Also context object contains references to different resource which will be required to draw the view..

There is very goog article on different types of contexts in android.If you go throught this article hopefully you will get better understanding of context.

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Answer (score 5):

A `View` requires a `Context` for many reasons. Some reasons from grepping [`View.java`source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java):

- Resources such as platform dimensions
- Styled attributes
- Target SDK version from application manifest for backward compatibility modes
- Reference to an activity when resolving `onClick` attributes
- System services such as Accessibility Manager
- Providing a context with `getContext()`